# Tomcat war deployment gives 404 when using annotations instead of web.xml

Tags: spring, docker, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to learn Spring framework. When I use Spring annotation for configuration instead of web.xml and deploy war file on Tomcat in Docker container, it gives 404 error. After switching to web.xml and servlet.xml configuration, it gives no error.

My config file:

```
package com.janfranco.mvctutorial.config;

...

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

My servlet file:

```
package com.janfranco.mvctutorial.config;

...

public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

I use Maven for management. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8

COPY target/mvctutorial.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

How can I use annotations and get rid of xml configs?

Edit:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>mvctutorial</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you remove `web.xml` entirely, can you add it to the question? It is possible to disable annotation scanning through the `metadata-complete` attribute and `<absolute-ordering>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I remove web.xml and servlet.xml files when using annotations config.